# Preventing "combining signed and unsigned types widened both operands" compiler warning

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

This code, which is used to setup a component, produces a compiler warning:

```
[DCC Warning] Unit1.pas(742): W1024 Combining signed and unsigned types 
                            - widened both operands
```

```pascal
var
  iPrecision: cardinal;
  iRadius: cardinal;
  iActive: boolean;
  iInProximity: boolean;

iPrecision := Max(50, 100 - (3 + 2 * ord(iActive and iInProximity)) * iRadius);
```

Can this be typecast somehow to prevent a compiler warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, `ord()` returns an `integer`, so needs to be explicitely type-casted to `cardinal`, by changing `ord()` into `cardinal()` as such:

```
iPrecision := Max(50, 100 - (3 + 2 * cardinal(iActive and iInProximity)) * iRadius);
```

You will get rid of the warning, and your code will be almost the same.

Answer (score 5):

Arnaud has explained that `ord()` returns a signed value which is the source of the warning. Both Arnaud and Ken have suggested how to remove the warning by avoiding the use of unsigned operands.

I would like to offer an alternative opinion and suggest that you instead choose to use signed operands. Let's suppose that you perform the calculation using only signed operands. Consider the following program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Math;

function CalcPrecision(Radius: cardinal; Active, InProximity: boolean): Cardinal;
begin
  Result := Max(50, 100-(3+2*Cardinal(Active and InProximity))*Radius);
end;

begin
  Writeln(CalcPrecision(1000, True, True));
  Readln;
end.
```

I'm sure that you would hope that the output of this program would be 50. It's not. The output is 4294962396.

What happens is that you perform `100-X` in an unsigned context where `X>100`. When you do this you have integer overflow and the result is a very large positive value. Since you are using unsigned arithmetic, you cannot expect this to be a negative value because there are no negative values in unsigned.

Of course, if the compiler option for overflow checking was enabled, you would encounter a runtime error. But even that is not what you want. The simple way to get the answer you need is to perform the operation using signed arithmetic.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Math;

function CalcPrecision(Radius: Integer; Active, InProximity: boolean): Integer;
begin
  Result := Max(50, 100-(3+2*ord(Active and InProximity))*Radius);
end;

begin
  Writeln(CalcPrecision(1000, True, True));
  Readln;
end.
```

And this program produces the desired output of 50.

If for some reason, you need to store the value back to an unsigned variable, then do that outside the calculation. It's important for the reasons illustrated above that the calculation is performed with signed values.

```
....
var
  Precision: Cardinal;
begin
  Precision := CalcPrecision(1000, True, True);
  Writeln(Precision);
  Readln;
end.
```

Of course, it's true that you can come up with input values that will overflow the calculation, even if it is written using signed arithmetic. But in practise you will find that such input is exceptionally unlikely. On the other hand, it's very easy to trip your equation up when it is performed unsigned, using quite reasonable input data.

Comment: @Bill I'd quite like to understand what it is about this answer that you don't like. Do you perhaps not understand the point that I am making? Or do you think that what I am saying is not accurate.

Comment: I'd suspect it's probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266462/preventing-combining-signed-and-unsigned-types-widened-both-operands-compiler/17266550?noredirect=1#comment25029232_17266550. Also, my first suggestion was to switch to using a singed type, with the BoolValue an alternative if the first wasn't possible for some reason.

Comment: @Ken It's always possible to use a signed value for the arithmetic. You can feed in unsigned values, and store the result to an unsigned value. I'm sure you know this. But if you do the arithmetic in unsigned, then expect trouble with overflow.  I'm guessing that the issue is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001728/update-tlabels-in-omnithread and there's a revenge DV

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the compiler warning by either

- Changing your `Cardinal` variables to a signed type such as `Integer`
- Use a slight workaround like this:

```
var
  ...
const
  BoolValues: array[Boolean] of Cardinal = (0, 1);
begin
  ...
  iPrecision := Max(50, 100 - (3 + 2 * BoolValues[iActive and iInProximity]) * iRadius);
end;
```

Comment: I choose to try the latter, because iPrecision and iRadius are component properties which I can not change... but I still get the warning.

Comment: I guess for now I'll use {$WARNINGS OFF} and {$WARNINGS ON}

Comment: @Bill: Check my edit to the declaration of `BoolValues`. I tested and compiled the code I posted, and it generates zero warnings. Don't give up so quickly. :-)

Comment: Thanks Ken... it generates zero warnings... Good by {$WARNINGS OFF}!

Comment: I much prefer this approach in comparison to using `ord()` or `Cardinal()`. It should be treated as an implementation that `False` has ordinal 0 and True has ordinal 1. Personally I'd write it more compactly as `IfThen(iActive and iInProximity, 1, 0)`. That said, the danger of integer overflow means that I would not use unsigned arithmetic here.