# Delphi compiler warning for passing signed to unsigned

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I recently tried using **Range Checking** in my application, in an attempt to catch array bounds violations, etc.

Unfortuantly this has caused quite a few non-errors relating to `HRESULT`:

```
var
    hr: HRESULT;
begin
    hr := E_UNEXPECTED;
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(hr));
```

The call to `SysErrorMessage` fails with a **ERangeError**. That is because:

```
HRESULT = type Longint;  { from wtypes.h }

function SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode: Cardinal): string;
```

### Manually typecast

The solution is simple: manually force a conversion to `Cardinal` every time i pass an `HRESULT` to `SysErrorMessage`.

This works well enough for code in the current project i'm working on - do a search for `SysErrorMessage` and scan the results for where I might be passing an `HRESULT`:

[image]

But it fails when there is code in shared libraries. And it also fails when there might be other constructs where i'm passing a signed to unsigned and vice versa.

### Can the compiler just tell me?

Does the compiler have a warning option to catch when i mix signed and unsigned types? Obviously i'm going to disable the use of range checking.

### See also

- [W1024 Combining signed and unsigned types - widened both operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430223/w1024-combining-signed-and-unsigned-types-widened-both-operands)
- [Preventing "combining signed and unsigned types widened both operands" compiler warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266462/preventing-combining-signed-and-unsigned-types-widened-both-operands-compiler)
- [Range checking](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Range_checking)
- [[D2009] I think SysErrorMessage is wrong...](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.rtl/200810/081007268.html)

### Bonus

All the [WinSock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx) functions return Integer:

```
int WSAAPI getaddrinfo(
  _In_opt_       PCSTR      pNodeName,
  _In_opt_       PCSTR      pServiceName,
  _In_opt_ const ADDRINFOA  *pHints,
  _Out_          PADDRINFOA *ppResult
);
```

[and](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
int WSAGetLastError(void);
```

Jcl/Jvcl has a lot of fixin to be doin.

Comment: All your code passing `HResult` values to `SysErrorMessage` is wrong anyway. That function calls `FormatMessage`, which is for formatting Win32 error codes, not COM error codes. Responses to your fourth "see also" link address that. If your COM error code starts with `FACILITY_WIN32`, then you can strip those bits (as by `HResultFromWin32`) and pass the resulting code to `SysErrorMessage`, but if `SysErrorMessage` has actually been working with COM error codes, that's undocumented behavior that you shouldn't rely on anyway.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the WinSock functions return signed integers, but there's no problem in practice because all the error codes they return are positive, so there's no danger of exceeding the bounds of Cardinal.

Comment: @RobKennedy: to extract a Win32 error code from an `HRESULT` that uses `FACILITY_WIN32`, you have to use `HRESULT_CODE()`, not `HResultFromWin32()`. But even then, it is not always possible to convert such an `HRESULT` to a Win32 error code. See Raymond Chen's blog on that issue: [How do I convert an HRESULT to a Win32 error code?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/03/942851.aspx).

Comment: @RobKennedy [Microsoft also uses `FormatMessage` to format HRESULTs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/security/system/security/cryptography/x509/x509utils.cs,559). They also force a typecast to `uint` on the way in. Also, [`FormatMessage` is able to handle system HRESULTs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/24/where-s-dxerr-lib.aspx)

Comment: FormatMessage can accept HRESULTS. But it will only yield meaningful results with system errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the compiler have a warning option to catch when i mix signed and unsigned types?

W1024 will collect mixed arithmetic and comparisons. But there's nothing at compile time for assignment or parameter passing, which is essentially the same as assignment.